# Файлы с переменными окружения -- зло ли?

Tags: веб-программирование, переменные, непрерывная-интеграция, kubernetes, ci-cd

У меня есть твёрдое убеждение, что `*.env` - файлики — это не очень хорошо. Да, они имеют место быть, особенно на ранних этапах проекта. Но, в идеале, от них лучше избавиться. Особенно, когда мы начинаем внедрение CI/CD и т.п. Но я не могу это аргументировать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на этот вопрос даётся на основании:

1. [12-factor-methodology-config](https://12factor.net/config) , а лучше прочитать [целиком](https://12factor.net)
2. [12-factor-methodology-wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve-Factor_App_methodology)
3. [habr](https://habr.com/ru/post/261171/) (Конфигурация — это свойства среды выполнения). Это самая главная фраза для данного ответа. По тексту можно найти

Теперь к деталям:

1. Коль скоро, конфигурация — это свойство среды (т.е. ОС), то именно из неё должны поступать переменные.
2. Приложению должно быть индеферентно, кто и как подсовывает ему переменные. Т.е. фактически приложение ничего не знает о файликах с конфигурацими и не должно знать.
3. В подходе с `.env`-файлами, мы огребём на этапе сборки с тем, что нужно решать, что загружать: то ли конфиги, то ли переменные окружения.
4. Если у Вас есть [vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) и [consul](https://www.consul.io/), то там переменные будут прокидываться именно как переменные окружения.
5. В коде возникает загрузчик, который не получится протестировать нормально, так как он и не библиотека, а фуникця, у которой слишком ограниченный функционал. Что с ним делать не ясно. Это потенциальная уязвимость. Плюс дополнительный код. Плюс место для багов, которые сложно будет отловить.
6. В целом, такой подход может быть. Но в том случае, если у нас будет отдельная библиотека, которая занимается загрузкой переменных, конфигов и всего остального. Да, в ней можно реализовать разные виды загрузок: из разных видов конфигов, из переменных и т.д. Т.е. эта библиотека может отвечать за несколько видов сред: файлы, конфиги, env-файлы, переменные окружения и т.п.

На заметку. Есть замечательный [плагин](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7861-envfile) для Goland. Плагин умеет загружать переменные окружения